# Select rows based on column value (including NA's) in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to separate assessed blocks from the ones that were not assessed. I do know how to select certain rows on the basis of a column value, however in this particular data set only a few rows indicate whether or not it was assessed (which would then imply the assessment of the following rows):

e.g.:

```
     Block Number        Assessment block         Target or stimuli
     1                   no                       gaps
                                                  target         
                                                  gaps
                                                  target
                                                  gaps
                                                  target
     2                   no                       gaps 
                                                  target
                                                  gaps
                                                  target
                                                  gaps
                                                  target
     3                   yes                      gaps
                                                  target   
                                                  gaps
                                                  target
                                                  gaps
                                                  target
                                                  gaps
     4                   yes                      target
                                                  gaps
                                                  target 
                                                  gaps
```

How do I select the assessed blocks only, without losing the data of the rows that do not specify whether or not they were assessed?

E.g select rows from block 3 onward

I have to do this for 300 files and the assessed block always starts at a different row number

Any help would be appreciated!! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-c('yes','no', 'yes', NA, 'yes')
e<-c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
x<-data.frame(a, b, e)
x[which(is.na(x$b) | x$b == 'yes'),]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response @Cut-n-paster ! however this only gives the rows that do clarify assessment, not the rows in between

Comment: Do you mean if there are 'no' inbetween the 'yes', it needs to be included? or everything from the first start of 'yes' to the last?

Comment: I mean that I also need the 'target or stimuli' information in between the first assessed block (3,yes) and the second (4,yes). As the column containing assessment information does not contain any yes's or no's. I hope you know what I mean! :) @Cut-n-paster

Comment: can you confirm those are the empty rows contains just the last column values?

Comment: I mean everything from the first yes to the last, in response to your earlier question

Answer (score 0):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

You can use `which` to deal with the `NA` problem when comparing simply using `==`.

**LONG ANSWER:**

Given this example df:

```
test <- data.frame(Block_Number = c(1,2,3,4,5),
           Assessment_Block = c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", NA))
```

If I understood correctly, you did something like this:

```
test[test$Assessment_Block == "yes",]
```

which also returned column 5 (in my example), that has `NA` in Assessment_Block. If you add `which`, it should fix the problem:

```
test[which(test$Assessment_Block == "yes"),]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! @csgroen however, this returns only the rows that do contain information on the assessment block, it does not return the information in between block 3 and 4, for example.